# How can I add a button to the layout? - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, desktop-application, desktop

I cannot find any methods to add the button to the layout.

I am trying to add the child (button) to the layout, but I can't find any methods to do so.

**Source Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            Button button = new Button {Height = 100, Width = 100, Text = "Test"};
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do that in the constructor of `Form1`: `Button button = new Button { ... }; this.Controls.Add(button);`. If for some reason, you want to do this in `Main()` (I don't think there's a good reason), just assign the instance of the form to a variable and add the button to its `Controls` collection. `Form1 frm = new Form1(); frm.Controls.Add(button); Application.Run(frm);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You open your project in Visual Studio 2019 (not Visual Studio Code, not JetBrains Rider) - free versions for which exist if your context qualifies for the license. If you don't qualify for a free license, you[r workplace] can easily afford a license of some form
- You double click Form1 in the solution explorer and then you see something that looks like what the form will look like when you run the program, and you open the controls tool panel and drag a button out of it and drop it onto the form...

But if you want to get into hand-writing the volumes of boring repetitive code to build a UI then you add controls to the Controls collection of other controls, viz:

```
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        Button button = new Button {Height = 100, Width = 100, Text = "Test"};
        f.Controls.Add(button);

        Application.Run(f);
```

Every Control has a Controls collection to which other Controls can be added (not just things you think of as "things that have child controls, like Panel or GroupBox" - some controls are collections of other controls, like a NumericUpDown is a textbox and a couple of buttons)

For an example of how much code you'll need to write, lay out a reasonable looking UI in the design view and then open the Form1.Designer.cs - you'll see why we do it with the aid of a design tool! :)

---

> Wouldn't it be faster to learn if I didn't use the Designer tool?

IMO, no. That's like saying "wouldn't it be faster to learn if I hand code an SVG in notepad rather than using Inkscape/Gimp to draw the image visually.. or create a PNG by typing the bytes out in a hex editor"

Getting so close to the raw low level means you end up "not being able to see the wood for the trees" and it hinders your learning. For a lengthy discourse on abstractions and why we use them/how they apply to every daily process including learning and operating in life, see the comment trail

Comment: When I try to open the Designer tool, it does not work.

I also have a question: Wouldn't it be faster to learn if **I didn't use** the Designer tool?

Comment: For windows forms? No, definitely not. That's like asking "wouldn't it be faster to get to work if I take the top off my car engine and push the positions up and down with my hands". We have this thing in life called "layers of abstraction" - we hide the complexity of certain tasks from the end user because to go into every little detail is overwhelming and makes no sense. It starts very early on, telling children "you can't take away 3 sweets when you only have 2" and then it's "actually we can have negative numbers but you can't square root them", then it's "so there are imaginary numbers.."

Comment: I must agree with you there.

Comment: When I try to open the Designer tool, it does not work

Comment: We don't jump straight to teaching 3 year olds quantum entanglement. Same for the computer; you didn't start programming by grabbing a book on assembly language or building a cpu on a breadboard, writing network card drivers then implementing two, http, etc just so you could make a web request - you just write a line of code that says webclient.downloadstring(url) and a huge amount of nuts and bolts are hidden from you. I've been using C# winforms for the entire time it has existed and the only time I write ui code manually is to post on SO as a demo with a "paste this into a new project"

Comment: I'd scrap the project and start again with a new one; when you make a winforms project it should open the first form's designer for you as the first thing you see when you create the project ; if it doesn't then perhaps eg the Form1.resx got deleted and VS dropped to just treating it like any other c# class. Be sure you're creating a winforms style project rather than eg a blank one

Comment: I'm using JetBrains Rider, not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Problem solved, I missed the button.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, do you mean that you always use the Designer tool when developing user interfaces?

Comment: Pretty much; as noted I do occasionally sling together a very basic "one textbox and one buton" UI when I'm trying to show something on SO, so I can say "make a new project and paste this entire code over the top of the Form1 it creates" but for anything involved I mostly use design tools wherever possible - form designers, dataset designers, swagger/autorest/wcf/addreference because the volume and quality of code they produce vs the rate they produce it at means there is little to be gained by doing it manually. The only manual UI coding I do is web stuff and i find it incredibly tedious

Comment: I am asking the question again because you did not answer my question completely.

Comment: You said: "For window forms? No, definitely not", but why you only gave me examples. I mean, if the user develops the user interface himself and not from the designer tool, then he would learn more or not?

Comment: *if the user develops the user interface himself and not from the designer tool, then he would learn more or not* - you probably would, eventually but I suppose it would be like learning a language my memorizing a dictionary for that language. It's really hard to see how anything fits together if you immediately go the the finest grained level of detail possible and try to work it out from there. Think about your life; the bread you've just eaten - you *could* grow that wheat, and thresh it and grind it to flour, and bake it into bread, but you don't. You hand a lot of it off to automation

Comment: I'm not saying "never try to build a UI by hand" but if you use a a viual designer first, and then look at what it did you'll have an understanding of what the fine grained detail looks like as a big picture, and it will help you interpret the fine grained detail. I'm 100% confident that you might create one or two UIs by hand, but for massive, involved ones you'll just use the designer, because there simply is no point not doing - it's all just setting properties of length, width, height, text, position, font and adding them to a collection: boring and nothing to be gained from doing manually

Comment: I've never used Rider.. If it doesn't have a UI designer then why cut one leg off at the knee when you're trying to run a marathon? Install Visual Studio Community (free) as well as Rider, and use VS to do the UI, and look what it did (you can go back to Rider at any time).

Comment: I have fixed the problem. There are no more problems.

Comment: _"I'm 100% confident that you might create one or two UIs by hand, but for massive"_ -

If the user develops massive UIs, he will learn more and more.

If I understood your answers correctly, you mean that using the Designer Tool can save you time and effort.

Comment: I have another question: What do you mean by "SO" ?

Comment: *the Designer Tool can save you time and effort* - it's not just that. Look at the shirt you're wearing - you could plant your own cotton plant, pick it, spin it into cotton, weave it into cloth, cut it to shape, sew it into a shirt.. But if you're being consistent with your "do everything at the lowest level to learn all about it) you'll also have to make your won scissors, build your own sewing machine... And the end output will take longer, cost more&quality won't be as good as the shirt you could have bought that it the output of a highly refined set of steps that produce excellent shirts.

Comment: You use abstractions every minute of every day of your life; people want something that they can do by hand, but automation makes a better job of it all round, so they put effort into creating the automation. Someone invented a designer- use it, and spend more time writing the truly innovative parts of your program rather than spending days setting the pixel position of every button. SO = stackoverflow

Comment: The designer only works in Visual Studio, it doesn't work in VS Code. Can't comment about non Microsoft IDEs.
Building a Windows Forms app outside Visual Studio (or another IDE that provides a Windows Forms designer)  is a thankless task.

Comment: Indeed, and at no point did I mention VSC? I will, however, add a note to the answer.. because OP's not using Visual Studio Anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the button to your Form, not to the Main method!

The issue with your code is that it's in the wrong place - actually, it only runs *after the form is closed*, because `Application.Run` will run your form in a message loop, allowing UI events to fire.

You can either use the Visual Studio WinForms Designer (if using Visual Studio), or manually add the code *after the `InitializeComponent()` method* - so, either right in the constructor, or in any of the Form startup events, such as Load or Shown.

It's likewise very important to add the `Button` (or any dynamically instantiated control, for that matter) to the `Controls` collection of the Form - otherwise, your `Button` won't be displayed:

```cs
Button button = new Button {Height = 100, Width = 100, Text = "Test"};
this.Controls.Add(button);
```

There are certainly use cases for dynamic generation of controls; however, it's very unusual to build out your controls manually *before the form even runs* - in most cases of dynamic control generation, the form is up and running - the dynamic generation is in response to some user action. I recommend using the designer for general UI layout.